# use jquery .filter() to filter by multiple criteria

Tags: jquery

I have divs that i want to filter by their data attributes. the first filter is by the data-title attribute which is filtered by a text input. the second filter i want to implement is by data-tags attribute. an example of the data-tags is: data-tags="js, php, css"

when a user clicks a tag button, that tag is added to the tags array. i want to be able to filter the divs by both attributes, data-title and data-tags.

here is a sample div

```
<div id="work-card-0" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project" data-tags="js,php,css" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
```

here is the jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('work.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(k, v) {
     $("#work-section").append("<div id='work-card-" + v.id + "' class='work-card col-md-3 text-center' data-title='" + v.title + "' data-tags='" + v.tag + "'><img class='work-img img-responsive' src='" + v.image + "'><h3 class='work-title'>" + v.title + "</h3><p class='work-p'>" + v.desc + "</p><a class='btn btn-primary' href='" + v.link + "' target='_blank'>View</a></div>");
    });
   });
  });



  $("#filter").on('keyup', function() {
   $("#filter-form").submit();
  });

  var tags = [];
  $(".tag").on('click', function() {
   var tag = $(this).attr('value');
   if (tags.indexOf(tag) == -1) tags.push(tag);
   getTags();
  });

  function getTags() {
   $("#tag-holder ul").empty();
   for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    $("#tag-holder ul").append("<li value='" + i + "'>" + tags[i] + "</li>");
   }
  }

  //remove tags
  $("#tag-holder ul").on('click', 'li', function() {
   var tag = $(this).attr('value');
   tags.splice(tag, 1);
   getTags();
  });

  $("#filter-form").on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   getTags();
   var search = $("#filter").val();

   $.ajax({
    url: 'work.html'
   }).done(function() {

    $(".work-card").hide();
    $(".work-card").filter(function() {
     return ($(this).data('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    }).filter(function() {
     // filter here by tag
    }).show();
   });
  });


  $("#reset-btn").on('click', function() {
   $("#filter").val("");
   tags = [];
   getTags();
   $(".work-card").show();
  });

 });
```

the filter-form form has the input and all the buttons for the tags. when it is submitted the divs are filtered. the title filter works. How can i also filter by data-tags. i want the filter to filter by both data-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most effective method as filters in **jQuery** are great but this is a simple solution which will help you quickly I think...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var searchedTags = ["html", "js"];
 
 $(".work-card").hide();
 $(".work-card").filter(function() {
  return ($(this).data('title').toLowerCase().indexOf("test") > -1);
 }).filter(function() {
  var result = false;
  var tags = $(this).data("tags").split(",");
  if (searchedTags && tags && (tags instanceof Array)) {
   for(var i in searchedTags) {
    var searchedTag = (searchedTags[i]).toLowerCase();
    console.log("  Searched Tag: " + searchedTags[i]);
    result = result || ($.inArray(searchedTags[i], tags) != -1);
   }
  }
  return result;
 }).show();
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="work-card-0" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 1" data-tags="css" style=""><h3 class="work-title">Test project 1 (css)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-1" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 2" data-tags="css,js" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 2 (css/js)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-2" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 3" data-tags="php,html" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 3 (php/html)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-3" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 4" data-tags="php,html" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 4 (js)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A interesting approch using **jQuery** custom filter, I think the filter implementation can be improved but too tired to do this now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var searchedTags = ["js", "css"];

  $.expr[':'].jobWorkFilter = function(elem, index, match) {
    var result = false;
  var tags = $(elem).data("tags").split(",");
  if (searchedTags && tags && (tags instanceof Array)) {
   for(var i in searchedTags) {
    var searchedTag = (searchedTags[i]).toLowerCase();
    console.log("  Searched Tag: " + searchedTags[i]);
    result = result || ($.inArray(searchedTags[i], tags) != -1);
   }
  }
  return result;
  };
    
  $(".work-card")
    .hide()
    .filter(".work-card[data-title*='Test']:jobWorkFilter()")
    .show();
    
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="work-card-0" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 1" data-tags="css" style=""><h3 class="work-title">Test project 1 (css)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-1" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 2" data-tags="css,js" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 2 (css/js)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-2" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 3" data-tags="php,html" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 3 (php/html)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div id="work-card-3" class="work-card col-md-3 text-center" data-title="Test project 4" data-tags="php,html" style=""><img class="work-img img-responsive" src="images/skier.png"><h3 class="work-title">Test project 4 (js)</h3><p class="work-p">This is a sample project</p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">View</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```